# Unable to insert into datetime2 sql column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to INSERT into a *datetime2* SQL column with the following code, but it does not seem to be working:

```
INSERT INTO TCLIENT (timestamp)
VALUES (2018-08-31T10:30:25);
```

Why is this not working? Is my format incorrect?

Comment: Put the datetime literal in single quotes

Comment: For future reference: "it does not seem to be working" doesn't tell us anything. If you get an error, please always post the error message!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

single quote is missing in your query:

```
INSERT INTO TCLIENT (timestamp)
       VALUES ('2018-08-31T10:30:25');
```

Comment: Ah ok, I thought that would be interpreted as a String. But it is working

Comment: I've checked the database, but when I use this, the value persisted in the database is NULL

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b74beac1b9777c64cb592e63b160fed3 - check here

Answer (score 0):

You need single quotes :

```
INSERT INTO TCLIENT (timestamp)
       VALUES ('2018-08-31T10:30:25');
```